# Game isn't running full screen Wine

Tags: wine, fullscreen

I installed Ubuntu and Need For Speed Most Wanted using PlayOnLinux

Wine version 1.6.2

I chose my screen resolution (1280x1024) in game and winecfg but when i'm playing window is leaving a gap on the top and i can't see bottom screen of the game.

Comment: Tried Alt + Enter?

Comment: yes, that isn't working

Comment: Have you tried pressing Command to escape the virtual machine and manually adjusting the screen?

Comment: I tried but nothing happens.

Comment: i do debug and i got this error fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8. can that be a problem?

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, PlayOnLinux does not work, so I found the alternative to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut